# Split comma separated string/value to columns

Tags: libreoffice-calc, text-to-column

I have comma separated `CODE` value in column "A2" and "A3"

> Screenshot 1

[image]

I want to split the comma separated `CODE` values to `SP_1`,`SP_2` ... `SP_10` columns like as the below screenshot

> Screenshot 2

[image]

Is there any formula to do this?

Comment: Data, Data Tools, Text-to-Columns, Delimited, Comma, Destination: $B$2, Finish

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! It is working now. @Jeeped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data, Data Tools, Text-to-Columns, Delimited, Comma, Destination: $B$2, Finish

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The standard method is Text to Column Wizard, in addition you can use VBA code also.